# Second-person Damon Runyon stories

Tags: short-stories, narrator, damon-runyon

Which of Damon Runyon's writings are written completely using the second person point of view?

One example of this is [A Change of Heart by Michel Butor](https://www.theguardian.com/books/booksblog/2013/aug/01/summer-voyages-la-modification-michel-butor) . I heard [John Sayles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Sayles#Novels) refer to Damon Runyon doing this, but I forget if he cited a particular example. That is what I am looking for.

Comment: I don't think you meant second person.  Second person narrative would be like <<You   feel hungry. You decide it's lunchtime. You walk to the nearest diner where you look at the menu. You order a burger.>>  and so on.  There are few stories by ANY author written in the second person, other than choose-your-own-adaventure.   I'm not sure if you want 1st person ( "I am feeling hungry" )  or 3rd person ("he is feeling hungry")  Both are rare  in Runyon stories.  Usually it's a 1st person framing story and 3rd person narrative.

Comment: To clarify, I meant that it is rare for Runyon stories to be completely 1st or completely 3rd person.  Usually, it's a mixture of both.

Comment: Are you confusing **person** (first, second or third, i.e. which pronoun the "narrator" uses) with **POV** (which character is providing the perspective)? Please [edit] your post to make it clear what you're asking. For further guidance, see [ask] and take our LitSE [Tour]. :-)

Comment: I definitely do mean second person narrative. One example is A Change of Heart by Michel Butor (https://www.theguardian.com/books/booksblog/2013/aug/01/summer-voyages-la-modification-michel-butor).   I heard John Sayles refer to Damon Runyon doing this, but I forget if he cited a particular example.  That is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 3):

If you mean second person narrative, a quick look through my Damon Runyon short story collection "From First to Last" reveals that the vast majority of the stories in that volume are written in the first person, and all but one of the remaining stories are in the third person.

The one exception is the two-page story "No Life", which *starts* in the second person: "You have been noticing an uneasy sensation in region of the Darby Kelly and the croaker says it looks to him like it might be—–"

However, the rest of the story is entirely dialogue, with no tags, so this story doesn't qualify for your request for "writings ... written *completely* using the second person" (my emphasis).

You can search for other second-person narratives by looking through the [Damon Runyon Omnibus](https://gutenberg.net.au/ebooks11/1100651h.html) of 47 short stories: it's a free e-book by Project Gutenberg Australia.